# How many turbine blades, engine seals and bearings do reusable rocket engines have and how are they inspected?

Tags: spacex, rockets, engines

From previous year statements of SpaceX representatives, the most difficult and longest part of used F9 booster refurbishment are inspections of the most volatile parts of the booster's nine Merlin engines.

Based on their statements, they must always inspect if engines seals are holding and engines bearings are working properly, and also inspect Merlin turbine blades because of their intense fatigue during flight.

Does anybody know how many turbine blades, engine seals and bearings one Merlin can have and how are they inspected? How they can scan turbine blades for cracks, inspect if seals are holding and bearings are working properly without disassembling the engine - or is partial engine disassembly part of the engines inspections? Can these inspections be fully automated or do you need experienced staff for it?

Just for comparison, how many turbine blades, engine seals and bearings did the Shuttle RS-25 have and how many the new SpaceX Raptor engine can have? What has SpaceX done to make the Raptor post fight inspections faster and less difficult?

Comment: Any answer to this is going to be pretty much exclusively about the RS-25. It's highly unlikely you'll get this kind of detail for the Merlin or Raptor. Those are all very closely guarded trade secrets. (Even taking a simple photo of the bottom of a Falcon 9 used to be off-limits at some point.)

Comment: Maybe, I wanted at least raw count estimate of mentioned parts for Merlin and Raptor. RS-25 was completely disassembled for post fight inspections in the first half of Shuttle program, but not in second half. So question is how they could inspect all mentioned parts without at least partially disassembling engines.

Comment: SpaceX did inspect the early engines using borescopes, which is part of why the turnaround between early reflights was several months, but they have also said that the interior of the Merlin 1D is essentially both maintenance *and* inspection-free. They just do a test firing, and upon any irregularities swap out a whole engine. Presumably the suspect engine then gets a full inspect and/or disassembly. Posted as a comment not answer because i'm not chasing up the supporting tweets for this.

Comment: @PcMan I can imagine using borescopes to check if engine seals are holding, but how can you can inspect (only with borescopes) if all bearings work properly or scan all turbine blades for cracks and defects. Don't you need UV light or X-ray scanning for this. Can you explain what " essentially both maintenance and inspection-free " mean.  From wiki. list of F9 boosters it looks like every booster still need about 18-20 days long refurbishment and based on SX statements most time should take inspections of used HW, so it looks that some engine inspections still take place after every flight.

Comment: 1/2 Don't have time to search for all articles that I remember from previous year, but from this one from March 1, 2021 https://spaceflightnow.com/2021/03/01/component-fatigue-caused-early-shutdown-of-merlin-engine-on-last-spacex-launch/ it doesn't look like engine refurbishment is already maintenance and inspection free. Quote 1 " SpaceX engineers can take lessons learned from Starlink launches and determine where to add more inspections during rocket refurbishment, and what components need to be replaced between Falcon 9 flights."

Comment: 2/2 Quote 2 “Here’s where we need more inspections, here are the kinds of components we need to replace, and here’s where we can actually upgrade the system, the algorithms, on the vehicle to even further detect and control what the vehicle needs to do, and that’s what we’re doing as we move forward, he said " (source Benji Reed, senior director of human spaceflight programs at SpaceX). It looks like both engines and engines section heatshield still need regular inspections.